# Trees: Calculate the cost of 2 paths and determine which is more expensive

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

This is my first question on this forum so I will try keep it clear.

I have 1 table `entity` with the following data:

```
ATTR1                ATTR2                 ATTR3                 ATTR4

A                    Level 1                null                   35
B                    Level 2                 A                     34
C                    Level 2                 A                     33
D                    Level 3                 B                     32
E                    Level 3                 B                     31
F                    Level 3                 C                     30
G                    Level 3                 C                     29
H                    Level 4                 D                     28
I                    Level 4                 D                     27
J                    Level 4                 E                     26
K                    Level 4                 E                     25
L                    Level 4                 F                     24
M                    Level 4                 F                     23
N                    Level 4                 G                     22
O                    Level 4                 G                     21
P                    Level 5                 H                     20
Q                    Level 5                 H                     19
R                    Level 5                 H                     18
S                    Level 5                 O                     17
```

Where `ATTR1` is the name of the node. It is also the primary key.
Where `ATTR2` is the level of the node.
Where `ATTR3` is the name of the node's parent node. `A` is the root and it has no parent nodes, therefore `NULL`.
Where `ATTR4` is the cost of the node.

Now the question:

- Given any part X and a leaf node Y (i.e. Y is a descendent of X), what is the most expensive path from either root to X or direct descendent of X to Y ?

In other words, let us say the X node is `D` and the Y node is `P`. The path from node to root would be `D-B-A` whereas the path from leaf to node would be `P-H-D`.

How is one to calculate the total cost of each path AND be able to say which is more expensive?

My approach was to do 2 recursive queries, 1 query for each path to find the SUM of each. The problem was that I was forced to create 2 tables and try to put all their data in 1. I feel I have hit a dead end and it is starting to look kinda long and not feasible.

Any help is appreciated, preferably in PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: +1 for a very useful first question. All the information is there, just like it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having create the table like this:

```
create table entity (attr1 text not null primary key,
                     attr2 text not null,
                     attr3 text,
                     attr4 int not null);
```

... and populated it with the data shown above, are you looking for something like this?:

```
with recursive cst as (
with req as (
select 'A'::text as top, 'D'::text as bottom
union all
select 'D'::text, 'P'::text
)
select
    top,
    bottom,
    top as last,
    top as path,
    attr4 as cost
  from req
  join entity on (top = attr1)
union
select
    top,
    bottom,
    attr1,
    path || '-' || attr1,
    cost + attr4
  from cst
  join entity on (attr3 = last)
), res as (
select * from cst where bottom = last
)
select path from res
   where cost = (select max(cost) from res);
```

Granted, the `req` CTE as a way to specify the request is a bit of hack, but I'm sure you can pretty up that part to be as you want it.  Also, this always shows the path from the "upper" to "lower" rather than "outside" to "inside", but I'm not sure whether that was important to you.  Anyway, this should be close enough to munge into what you want, I think.

Comment: Incredible ! That was exactly what I was looking for ! I'm still new to recursive queries and I wrecked my brain for hours on end before asking. The order of the answer ( The path ) makes no difference as long as it is the more costly of the two path. Thank you very much !

Comment: @postgresdbs: While Kevin's query certainly works, it leaves much room for improvement. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, save the level of your tree as `integer` not as (redundant and inappropriate) `text`.
The table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
  name   text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,level  int  NOT NULL
 ,parent text
 ,cost   int  NOT NULL);
```

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE val(root, leaf) AS (
    VALUES                          -- provide values here
     ('A'::text, 'D'::text)
    ,('D',       'P')
    ), x AS (
    SELECT v.root   AS name
          ,v.root   AS path
          ,r.cost   AS total
          ,1        AS path_len
          ,l.level - r.level AS len -- as break condition
    FROM   val    v
    JOIN   entity r ON r.name = root
    JOIN   entity l ON l.name = leaf

    UNION  ALL
    SELECT e.name                -- AS parent
          ,x.path || '-' || e.name -- AS path
          ,x.total + e.cost      -- AS total
          ,x.path_len + 1        -- AS path_len
          ,x.len                 -- AS len
    FROM   x
    JOIN   entity e ON e.parent = x.name
    WHERE  x.path_len <= x.len
    )
SELECT x.path, x.total
FROM   x
JOIN   val v ON x.name = v.leaf AND x.path_len > 1
ORDER  BY x.total DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Result:

```
path  | total
------+-------
A-B-D | 101
```

[Demo at sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/52e56/1)

#### Major points

- `VALUES` is faster / simpler / more intuitive for providing values.
- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, else the recursive union has to check for (non-existing in this case) duplicates every iteration.
- Don't include the columns `root` and `leaf` in the recursive CTE, they are dead weight.
- There is no need for a nested `WITH` clause. You can have plain CTEs in a `WITH RECURSIVE` clause.
- Most important for performance: In your model you know the lentgh of the path beforehand. Use it as break condition and don't calculate all paths to the bitter end - which can be *very* expensive with big trees.
- The final `SELECT` can also be largely simplified, no need for an aggregate function.
  Join to your values and pick the right paths. This way you can easily display any or all columns in the result if you want.